# Trying to install Windows 10 on iMac Catalina via Boot Camp

Tags: mac, bootcamp, windows, catalina

I have created the iso and it is on an external drive. It was setup up via Boot Camp as a Windows boot drive.
I followed the instructions. When my Mac restarts, it just goes back to the Mac sign in screen, then the desktop. The Disk utility shows the bootcamp partition as Windows NTFS, but appears empty. What do I need to get this to work?

[image: my mac specs]

Comment: Which version of Windows? Are you using flash drive to install?

Comment: Win 10. Am using a USB external drive. BOOTCAMP has already set the external drive files

Comment: Have you tried booting to the Mac Startup Manager and selecting the label `EFI Boot` under the external drive icon? You can access the Mac Startup Manager by restarting the Mac and immediately holding down the option key.